# how to insert more then 2 widgets in a row in pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I want to create a GUI with 3 elements in one row. Label, textedit and a button

I used for the Layout `QFormLayout()`

when I try to insert the 3 elements in the row with `layout.addRow(label,textEdit, button)`
I get a `TypeError: ..too many arguments`

how can I insert 3 elements while using a form layout ? Or do I need to use an other layout ?

below is the whole code

```
class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # your code will go here


        self.resize(700, 410)
        self.setWindowTitle("Youtube_mp3_Converter")

        # Widgets

        # Top Label
        top_label = qtw.QLabel()
        top_label.setText("Youtube_mp3_Converter")

        speicherort_label = qtw.QLabel()
        speicherort_label.setText("welcher Speicherort")
        test_label = qtw.QLabel()
        test_label.setText("test")

        # line edit
        self.speicherort_input = qtw.QLineEdit()

        # push buttons
        self.speicherort_button = qtw.QPushButton("Speicherort_bestaetigen")

        # layout
        layout = qtw.QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        layout.addRow(top_label)
        layout.addRow(self.speicherort_input, self.speicherort_button )



        self.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the line edit and the button in a separate `HBoxLayout` and add this layout to the form layout, e.g.

```
class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        ... 

        layout2 = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        layout2.addWidget(self.speicherort_input)
        layout2.addWidget(self.speicherort_button)

        layout.addRow(top_label, layout2)

        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Create `self.widget` and add`textEdit` and `button` to it, and then`layout.addRow (top_label, self.widget)`

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(700, 410)
        self.setWindowTitle("Youtube_mp3_Converter")

        # Widgets

        # Top Label
        top_label = QLabel()
        top_label.setText("Youtube mp3 \nConverter")   # +

        ''' 
        speicherort_label = QLabel()                       
        speicherort_label.setText("welcher Speicherort")
        test_label = QLabel()
        test_label.setText("test")
        '''

        self.widget = QWidget()                                 # +
        layout_h = QHBoxLayout(self.widget)                     # +

        # line edit
        self.speicherort_input = QLineEdit()
        # push buttons
        self.speicherort_button = QPushButton("Speicherort_bestaetigen")

        layout_h.addWidget(self.speicherort_input)              # +
        layout_h.addWidget(self.speicherort_button)             # +

        # layout
        layout = QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addRow(top_label, self.widget)                   # +
#        layout.addRow(self.speicherort_input, self.speicherort_button )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('fusion')
    w = MainWindow()  
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]